# Given n and a particular permutation s, find the next permutation in lexicographic order of elements 1-n (python)

Tags: python, permutation, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

For example, suppose we have `NextInOrder(10,(1,2,4,7))`, then with these two as inputs for the function, I wish to write a python function that returns `(1,2,4,8)` by finding the next permutation in lexicographic order where elements of the permutation are in the range `1-10`

So as another example `NextInOrder(10, (5,3,2,10))` would return `(5,3,4,1)`

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation will provide the answer (next permutation in lexicographic  order). towards end of article.

Comment: @ChrisCharley that only deals with cases where the permutation is the same length as the range the elements can be e.g. (1, 3, 2, 4, 5) not (1, 9, 4) like I want

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the specs closely enough. `10P4` for permutations of length 4 from numbers 1 to 10. I'm not sure the wikipedia article shows that. I'll reread it again to see if it shows that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a digit counter approach starting from the last position. Increase the last position to a value not in the previous positions. Backtrack to previous position(s) when the next value is out of range.

For example:

```
def nextPerm(N,P):
    result = list(P)           # mutable permutation
    i = len(P)-1               # position to advance (start with last)
    while i in range(len(P)):  # advance/backtrack loop
        result[i] += 1         # next value at position
        if result[i] > N:      # value beyond range
            result[i]=0
            i -= 1             # backtrack
        elif result[i] not in result[:i]: # distinct values only
            i += 1             # next position to advance
    return None if i<0 else tuple(result)
```

output:

```
P = (1,2,4,7)
while P:
    P = nextPerm(10,P)
    print(P)

(1, 2, 4, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 9)
(1, 2, 4, 10)
(1, 2, 5, 3)
(1, 2, 5, 4)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 5, 8)
(1, 2, 5, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 10)
(1, 2, 6, 3)
...
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. It was the elif statement at the end that I couldn’t work out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import permutations

def NextInOrder(n, current):
    perms = permutations(range(1, n+1), len(current))
    for perm in perms:
        if perm == current:
            return next(perms)
```

Demo:

```
>>> NextInOrder(10,(1,2,4,7))
(1, 2, 4, 8)
>>> NextInOrder(10, (5,3,2,10))
(5, 3, 4, 1)
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned this is part of my studies and they want us to code the function ourselves without importing any functions, but I can't work out how.